# MVC Razor syntax complexity management

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code block:

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Error))
{
    <h2>Please, choose a Start date.</h2>
}
else
{
    if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
var lastArticolo = "";
<h2>
    Rapporti Capoturno @Model.First().rapportoCT.DLinea
</h2>
<table>
    @foreach (var rapporto in Model)
    {
        if (lastArticolo != rapporto.rapportoCT.DCodArt)
        {
        <tr>
            <td class="td_title">
                @rapporto.rapportoCT.DCodArt
            </td>
        </tr>
            lastArticolo = rapporto.rapportoCT.DCodArt;
        } using (Html.BeginForm("ControlloQualita", "Rapporti"))
        {
        <tr>
            <td class="td_detail">
                @Html.TextBox("PalletControllati", rapporto.PalletControllati, new { style = "width:50px" })
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Update" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
}
else
{
    @:No records found 
}
}
```

I get error on the 6th line:
**else block is missing a closing character**

The error is located on the penult line, on the `@:No records found }`.

That is, because I have used the `@:` syntax, and so the closing `}` is interpreted as being part of the string!

Two options to **manually** resolve this (only after you have spotted where the problem is, of course!):

1. change the penult line to using an html tag: `<span>No records found</span> }`;
2. move the closing `{` on a new line;

I am an mvc newbie, so I could missing some points. I have used for quite a long time the ASP.NET webforms, so to me, this Razor syntax seems very confusing and error prone, only a little less (essentially thanks to MVC model-controller-view separation, MVC model binding and VS intellisense...) that the old ASP tag soup.

However this is a very simple View, and all the same I have had quite a lot of indentations headache and subtle to find syntax errors... I can't imagine when you have to debug some strange behaviour in a complex form.

So, in the end, my question is: how do you manage the raising complexity of Views with this razor syntax? Does the complexity scale up gracefully for complex Views?

Answer (score 1):

You need to instruct the razor engine to go back to C#, you can do it with `<text>`

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Error))
{
    <text><h2> Please, choose a Start date.</h2> </text>        
}
else
...
```

Note that you can use the simpler syntax: `@:`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to just change the nor records found line to:

```
else {
    @Html.Raw("No records found.") 
}
```

Comment: Serv im sorry for my down vote, i expediently pressed the wrong button. And im not able to alter my vote. For the record, this answer did help me

Comment: Naaaa, happens. Glad I could help.